# why my scrapy not run? I'm a new user of scrapy and it cannot create csv

Tags: python, scrapy

Below is all of the error, I think it must be some config or version wrong

`2022-11-01 19:43:58 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:`
`{'BOT_NAME': 'spider2022', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'spider2022.spiders', 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['spider2022.spiders'], 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ' '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}`
packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py", line 25, in 
from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
File "/Users/zhangyiran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 24, in 
from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
File "/Users/zhangyiran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 63, in 
from twisted.python.systemd import ListenFDs
File "/Users/zhangyiran/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/python/systemd.py", line 18, in 
from attrs import Factory, define
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs'
(venv) (base) zhangyiran@zhangyirandeair spider2022 % ``
"

Comment: For us to better understand your problem, could you please add the minimal reproducible example of your problem? That is, please include the contents of the .py file and the scrapy command.

Comment: based to this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs',     

try to install attrs in your environment

Comment: you are trying to import a package or module that doesn't exist in your enviornemnt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In one code I used import - 'from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess'. Then, in other spiders, I began to have the same problem as you. When I commented out the import CrawlerProcess - the problem went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me as well. I had to re-install the `attrs` package.

If `pip uninstall` is not working for you, You can try

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
rm -rf attrs-21.2.0.egg-info/
pip install attrs
```